# C++ Builder 6.0 - Error W8050 and Error W8058 while in compilation

Tags: c++, c++builder, compiler-warnings, c++builder-6

Today since the morning, when I'm trying to compile my application, I'm getting this warning:

> [C++ Warning] File.cpp(56): W8050 No type OBJ file present. Disabling
>   external types option.

According to the above, there should be no OBJ File present in the same folder where my application's files are. And in fact, they are there.

What's the problem?

I'm also receiving a W8058 warning:

> W8058 Cannot create pre-compiled header: write failed

Comment: Is your disk full? Have you changed permissions to where temporary files like that are written?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the error description at Embarcadero's website. But I couldn't tell if the disk is full or not. I'm pretty newbie at programming, and I really don't know where to look up for that temporary files folder.